# Limit the cardinality of a relationship in OWL

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology

I could not find this question already on SO, but I might have overlooked. My apologies if that is the case.

I'm trying to understand how to limit the cardinality of an object property using OWL. 
I'm not sure this fully/correctly describes what I'm trying to accomplish, so here's an example:

Consider the `hasWife` and `hasParent` properties described in [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language
Primer (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-primer-20121211/).

How do I state that any individual can only have 0 or 1 `hasWife` relationship, and must have exactly 2 `hasParent` relationships?

Extra points if you can tell me how to do this using WebProtégé.

Comment: make `hasWife` a functional property. and then add an axiom `owl:Thing SubClassOf hasParent exactly 2` - Note, those are **not** constraints but used for inference. In OWL we have Open World Assumption and no Unique Names Assumption, thus, a standard OWL DL reasoner will need extra axioms to work as expected. E.g. for axiom 1 you would have to declare both wifes beeing different from each other, otherwise the reasoner will infer that both wifes are the same entity. Similar issue for axiom 2, even more complicate here